# Add markers to google maps from external api url?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add all the markers in a map of google maps from the url of an api for example http://192.168.99.100:8080/api/v1/location this url show:

```
[{"nid":"23","title":"Acopio en xalapa","created":"1478207996","modified":"1478207996","body":"Acopio en xalapa","cover":"http:\/\/192.168.99.100:8080\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/original\/public?itok=GVqc4SZo","category":{"title":"Centro de acopio","detail":""},"address":"Venustiano carranza xalapa, veracruz","lat":"-123.1465","lng":"49.3026"},{"nid":"19","title":"Sucursal 1","created":"1476996732","modified":"1477666258","body":"esta es una sucursal muy bonita","cover":"http:\/\/192.168.99.100:8080\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/original\/public?itok=GVqc4SZo","category":{"title":"Sucursal","detail":""},"address":"Av tripulacion #34, col. nolose","lat":"-123.146567","lng":"49.302600"}]
```

I have to show all the markers in the map based on the latitude (lat) and length (lng) of that json generated by that url.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems  that  your content is  an array of objects then assuming that your resulting url is assigned at var named  my_var  you could accessing  this way

```
 my_var[0].nid  // 23
 my_var[0].title// Acopio en xalapa
 .....
 my_var[0].address // Venustiano carranza xalapa, veracruz
 my_var[0].lat  // -123.1465
 my_var[0].lng  // 49.3026

 my_var[1].nid  // 19
 my_var[1].title// Sucursal 1
 .....
 my_var[1].address // Av tripulacion #34, col. nolose
 my_var[1].lat  // -123.146567
 my_var[1].lng  //49.302600
```

Assuming you are able to create a map you can populate you map with markers this

```
var markers = [];

for (i=0; i<my_var.length; i++){
  markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( my_var[i].lat, my_var[i].lng),
    map: image
  });
```

Comment: Hi, @scaisEdge in each my_var [0] .nid the value of zero would be the index [i] of the for to get the values? Can you show me a more complete example please

Comment: The answer  provided  is based  on the data sample in your question .. In your question you have only 2 element (object) in array  so i have posted my_var[0] and my_var[1]  for explain you how the value are accessible . but for a general solution  .. you can  correctly iterate oven the array  (with a loop) an the you can access to each element using my_var[i]   ( where i is the index for iteration ) .. I hope this clarifies my answer

Comment: i understand, my question is based on the url http://192.168.99.100:8080/api/v1/location, I want to show all the markers that are that json dynamically, and put them on the map. In that url I can add more lat and lng from the backend, so I want it to be dynamic and not only limited to those in the example.

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is clear .. more simple or dinamic of this require  a coding service .. not SO